# Overlapping lists function returns False when True in python

Tags: python, list, overlap

I'm a programming semi-noob and am working through Torbjoern Lager's 46 Simple Python Exercises. This is number 10: Define a function overlapping() that takes two lists and returns True if they have at least one member in common, False otherwise. You may use your is_member() function, or the in operator, but for the sake of the exercise, you should (also) write it using two nested for-loops.

```
def over(list1,list2):
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            return i==j
```

I thought I had a nice, simple solution, but it can't recognize that the lists overlap, unless the overlapping elements are the first ones.

```
over(["a","b","c","d"],["e","f","a","h"])
```

returns False

```
over(["a","b","c","d"],["a","f","g","h"])
```

returns True

For some reason, it's not searching through all of the combinations. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `return` stops your function.

Comment: The Author have forget the if statement , it need to compare between Lists . A variation of this exercise .... it returns a List that contains only the elements the are common between the two list . def overlapping(): a = raw_input("Please give a list of number or word's: ").split() b = raw_input("Please give a list of number or word's: ").split() the_common = list(set(a).intersection(b)) # the intersection method return the elements the are common , in a new List . print the_common overlapping()

Answer (score 1):

It's not searching through all the combinations because you're returning on the first iteration of the nested loop. You could do this:

```
def over(list1,list2):
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            if i == j:
                return True

    return False
```

This returns `True` as soon as any overlap is found. If no overlap is ever found, it'll get to the last line and return `False`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you return `i==j` on the first iteration. Your function will justs compare list1[0] and list2[0]. The solution is to add `if`.
Here is an example:

```
def over(list1,list2):
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            if i == j:
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: I honest to God tried this the first time! I still had the same issue. Maybe I screwed up syntax or something?

Comment: Okay, reviewed old code. My return False was in the wrong place. Why doesn't this work if it's on the same level as the if?

Comment: @K.Solovieva, because then you will return `False` after first iteration of the first loop. Program will start your first loop, make all iterations and then see `return False`, I think that's not what you want

Comment: Oh sweet mother I get it! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should be testing with an if as suggested in the other answers as you are returning after the very first iteration but using [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) would be a nicer approach:

```
def over(list1,list2):
    return any(i ==j for i in list1 for j in list2)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
def over(list1,list2):
    for i in list1:
        for j in list2:
            if i == j:
                return True
    return False
```

short circuiting on a match and returning True if there is any match or returning False if there are none.

Or using sets for larger input would be the fastest approach:

```
def over(list1, list2):
    return not set(list1).isdisjoint(list2)
```

if `not set(list1).isdisjoint(list2)` is True we have at least one common element.

Answer (score -1):

When you execute the "return" stament de execution stops there, like it happens in Java. It returns true because you have 'a' in the first position in both arrays.

You can try this:

```
result = False;
for i in list1:
         for j in list2:
            if i == j:
                result=True;
return result
```

If you want it more efficient:

```
for i in list1:
     for j in list2:
        if i == j:
            return True;
return False;
```

Comment: So what would I need to substitute the end to for it to work? I tried an if/else, but I assume that would carry the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: @K.Solovieva, see my answer.

Comment: Okay, reviewed old code. My return False was in the wrong place. Why doesn't this work if it's on the same level as the if?