# Connect string value to a corresponding variable name

Tags: string, python-3.x, variables

This question has somehow to do with an earlier post from me. See here [overlap-of-nested-lists-creates-unwanted-gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642581/overlap-of-nested-lists-creates-unwanted-gap)

I think that I have found a solution but i can't figure out how to implement it.

First the relevant code since I think it is easier to explain my problem that way. I have prepared a fiddle to show the code:

[PYFiddle here](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/15f87c97-c4db-43b6-a64d-63a53b08cbb5/)

Each iteration fills a nested list in `ag` depending on the `axis`. The next iteration is supposed to fill the next nested list in `ag` but depending on the length of the list filled before.

The generell idea to realise this is as follows:

First I would assign each nested list within the top for-loop to a variable like that:

```
    x = ag[0]
    y = ag[1]
    z = ag[2]
```

In order to identify that first list I need to access `data_j` like that. I think the access would work that way.

```
data_j[i-1]['axis']
```

`data_j[i-1]['axis']` returns either `x`,`y` or `z` as `string`

Now I need to get the length of the list which corresponds to the axis returned from `data_j[i-1]['axis']`.

The problem is how do I connect the "value" of `data_j[i-1]['axis']` with  its corresponding `x = ag[0]`, `y = ag[1]` or `z = ag[2]`

Since `eval()` and `globals()` are bad practice I would need a push into the right direction. I couldn't find a solution

**EDIT:**
I think I figured out a way. Instead of taking the detour of using the actual axis name I will try to use the iterator `i` of the parent loop (See the fiddle) since it increases for each element from `data_j` it kinda creates an id which I think I can use to create a method to use it for the index of the nest to address the correct list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the iterator `i`. See the fiddle from my original post in order to comprehend what I did with the following piece of code:

```
if i < 0:
    cond = 0
else:
    cond = i
pred_axis = data_j[cond]['axis']      

if pred_axis == 'x':
    g = 0
elif pred_axis == 'y':
    g = 1
elif pred_axis == 'z':
    g = 2   

calc_size = len(ag[g])
n_offset = calc_size+offset
```

I haven't figured yet why `cond` must be `i` and not `i-1` but it works. As soon as I figure out the logic behind it I will post it.

**EDIT**: It doesn't work for `i` it works for `i-1`. My indices for the relevant list start at `1`. `ag[0]` is reserved for a constant which can be added if necessary for further calculations. So since the relevant indices are moved up by the value of `1` from the beginning already i don't need to decrease the iterator in each run.

Comment: `cond` is `max(0, i)`. What happens when `pred_axis` is not 'x', 'y', or 'z'? Does your code crash or silently re-use the latest `g` value?  `g` could be expressed as `axis_name2index[pred_axis]` with `axis_name2index` defined as `{'x': 0, 'y': 1, 'z': 2}`. BTW your code looks quite convoluted with all those indirect/index accesses which are often a sign you are doing something wrong/weird.

Comment: Since x, y, and z are being chosen from a list there is no option that there is something else than x,y or z. Thanks for the tip with `axis_name2index`. This is pretty good. 

My original code is quite extensive. I am using it for some calculations and their results are being saved in numpy-arrays. It might look convoluted but I am kinda new to programming and I am thankful for any advice to make things better. 
I don't  understand "`cond` is `max(0, i)`". Could explain that briefly?

Comment: I would still add an `else` with something like `assert False` because things like „there are only values 'x', 'y' or 'z', ever“ are sometimes not true if there's an error somewhere in the code.  `assert` woudn't be needed if what the programmer thinks is always true or false would be always right. :-) From the Zen of Python: „Errors should never pass silently.“ The first four lines can be replaced by `cond = max(0, i)` because that is essentially what the `if`/`else` construct does.